# Understanding onComplete from useMutation in Apollo

Tags: apollo-client, react-apollo

Reading [useMutation api documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#usemutation-api), a question came to my mind.

- `onCompleted` is executed no matter the result of the mutation? then when I access the information returned by the mutation with `onComplete: (data) => // make something with data`, `data` can also contain errors if the mutation returned some error from the server and I still need to validate that `data` has not contain errors?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [doc](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#options):

onCompleted is a callback function that's called when your mutation successfully completes with zero errors (or if errorPolicy is ignore and partial data is returned).

This function is passed the mutation's result data.